# Найти и удалить подстроку в строке

Tags: php

Я совсем новичёк в php, не могу разобраться.
Задача такая у меня есть css список и есть список только имён классов, которые нужно удалить.
Вот пример классов:

```css
.tooltip.bottom-right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%
}
```

Для поиска есть только **имя** класса (например, `.carousel`), без самих стилей.
Как с помощью php я могу найти и удалить класс с телом: вот это:

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
```

и в результате получить:

```css
.tooltip.bottom-right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: мы же тут про обработку `css` файла средствами пхп говорим, а то некоторые сомнения возникли? preg_replace вам в помощь https://regex101.com/r/2wJdSk/2

Comment: не css файла, просто текст

Answer (score 0):

Решение, которое мне подошло

```js
$originalCss = $_POST['originalCss'];
$classNames = $_POST['classNames'];
$pos1 = stripos($originalCss, $classNames);
$pos2 = stripos($originalCss, '}', $pos1);
$res = mb_strcut($originalCss, $pos1, $pos2 - $pos1 + 1);
$originalCss = str_replace($res, '', $originalCss);
```